# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PATCH, DELETE

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to understand why I am getting this error when submitting a form. I have found the workaround, but I don't necessarily understand why the workaround is needed and if it will cause issues later on. I am posting this to both understand the error but also to help any others who experience a similar issue.

The bolded workaround text below is what I did to get this functioning, adding '/posts/create'. However, in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers) the store path is displayed as '/post', 'PostController@store'. in advance.

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Mail\WelcomeMail;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}); 

Route::get('/email', function () {
    return new WelcomeMail();
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/contact/create', 'ContactController@create');
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@store');

Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');
Route::post('/posts/create', 'PostController@store'); **<-workaround**
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@show');
Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', 'PostController@edit');
Route::patch('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@update');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@destroy');
```

Form

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-cemter">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="card">
               <div class="card-header">Create New Post</div>


                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/posts/create" method="post">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Title</label>
                            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="titleHelp" placeholder="Enter Title" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('title') ?? $post->title }}">
                            <small id="titleHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Give your post a title that will describe your post easily</small>

                            @error ('title') <p style="color:red;">{{ $message }}</p> 
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="body">Body</label>
                            <input name="body" type="text" class="form-control" id="body" aria-describedby="bodyHelp" placeholder="Enter Post Body" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('body') ?? $post->body }}">
                             <small id="bodyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter as much detail you'd like!</small>

                             @error ('body') <p style="color:red;">{{ $message }}</p> 
                             @enderror
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PostContorller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('post.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $post = new Post();

        return view('post.create', compact ('post'));
    }

    public function store()
    {
        Post::create($this->validatedData());

        return redirect('/posts');
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('post.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('post.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    public function update(Post $post)
    {
        $post->update($this->validatedData());

        return \redirect('/posts');
    }

    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->delete();

        return redirect('/posts');
    }

    protected function validatedData()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
            //'photograph'=> nullable
            //'gif'=> nullable
        ]);
    }
}
```

Route:list

```
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | about                  |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | contact                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@store                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | contact/create         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@create                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | email                  |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm       | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | password/confirm       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web          |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | posts                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | posts/create           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@create                             | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | posts/create           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | posts/{post}           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@show                               | web,auth     |
|        | PATCH    | posts/{post}           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@update                             | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | posts/{post}           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@destroy                            | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | posts/{post}/edit      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@edit                               | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a route conflict somewhere, that's why you're getting that error. The code you posted only show your workaround which makes it difficult to know what's going on in the original code that causes the error.
I do not see your workaround causing any issue.

Comment: That's good news! In order to diagnose this properly what code would be beneficial to post?

Comment: The initial code without the workaround applied, so as to reproduce the error and then troubleshoot. Basically the web.php, .blade file and the controller

Comment: I revert back and have somehow fixed the error. I did not add @method('PUT" anywhere. Just changed the route back to '/posts' and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your blade view: `@method('PUT')` for a store call

```
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/posts/create" method="post">
                        @csrf 
                        @method('PUT')
```

on a side note, you can run the following artisan command to see what is the method required for each route if you ever get confused: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Tried this previously, the error just replaces Post with Put.

Comment: please share the content of your `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@method('PUT')`in your form view. HTML does not support PUT actions, using @method('PUT') you are tricking it to store the necessary information. Please view: [Laravel's Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing) for more clarification.

NOTE: Also the reason you are facing this issue is because you are using the same path twice, i.e.,

```
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');
Route::post('/posts/create', 'PostController@store'); **<-workaround**
```

the usage of '/posts/create' in both of this is giving you error. Please change it to `Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');`